# Trying to filter datagrid according to selections made in dropdown lists

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gridview

I have a View Feedback page with two drop down lists to filter the gridview of answers to questions. The 1st ddList is Modules, once this is selected, the 2nd ddList of Questions becomes enabled and the user can select a question to see the answers for it in relation to the module selected, OR they can select to see all answers to all questions for the selected module.

I have it working if they select a question but if they select all I simply get all answers, not just the ones specific to the selected module.

Sorry I know thats not the clearest explanation but any help would be awesome.

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tblModules
(
Module_ID nvarchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Module_Title nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tblQuestions
(
Q_ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Question_Text varchar(1000) NOT NULL

);

CREATE TABLE tblFeedback
(
Submission_ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Domain varchar(50) NOT NULL,
DateTime_Submitted datetime NOT NULL
Module_ID nvarchar(10)
FOREIGN KEY (Module_ID) REFERENCES tblModules (Module_ID);
);

CREATE TABLE tblAnswers
(
Q_ID int NOT NULL,
Submission_ID int NOT NULL,
Answer_Text varchar(max),
FOREIGN KEY (Q_ID) REFERENCES tblQuestions(Q_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Submission_ID) REFERENCES tblFeedback(Submission_ID)
);
```

Here is the snippet of code I'm using to construct the Sql statement which is used to select the data which is then bound to my grid.

```
                // If they have selected view all questions, get all answers for module
                if (ddQuestions.SelectedItem.Value == "all")
                {
                    //selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblAnswers ORDER BY Submission_ID";
                    selective = false;
                    //gridviewFeedback.Columns[3].Visible = true;

                    selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblAnswers A ";
                    selectQuery += "WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblModules M JOIN tblFeedback F ON M.Module_ID = F.Module_ID ";
                    selectQuery += "WHERE F.Module_ID = '" + this.selectedModuleID + "')";


                }
                // Instead, if they have selected a specific question, get the information for the selected module and question
                else
                {
                    selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblAnswers WHERE Q_ID = '" + qID + "' ORDER BY Submission_ID";
                    selective = true;
                    //gridviewFeedback.Columns[3].Visible = false;
                }


                DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter myCommand2;
                myCommand2 = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, myConnection);

                myCommand2.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myCommand2.Fill(objDs);

                gridviewFeedback.DataSource = objDs;
                gridviewFeedback.DataBind();
```

I think its my SQL statement as I'm not very experienced at SQL and have kind of edited a statement I used elsewhere that was given to me by someone else.

*UPDATE* Just realised my other statement isnt working either - its not providing module specific answers either.

Comment: People aren't going to be more likely to help you, nor are they going to help you more quickly just because you say it's urgent and use lots of exclamation points in the title. :)

Comment: After seeing what happened in your last question maybe you should run some unit tests first to see what you changed

Comment: @Kirk Woll - I wasn't trying to annoy people with excalmation points and saying its urgent.. It IS urgent (deadline tomorrow morning) and its stressing (hence the exclamation points)

Comment: @Kirk Woll, if it's due for tomorrow why are you asking this question now?

Comment: @Frank - You don't need to do that here. The reputation system pretty much ensures that people will attempt to answer questions quickly anyway. A lot of people, myself included, find such additions annoying. c.f. [Don't flag your question as “Urgent”, even if it is for you](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent)

Comment: Ok sorry folks, chalk it up to being a noob - I'm new to this site. This problem has me stressed out. No more exclamation/urgent flags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query instead. I think this should do it.
This should help you get all the answers belonging to a specific module

```
SELECT ans.* FROM tblAnswers ans, tblFeedback fb
WHERE ans.Submission_ID = fb.Submission_ID
AND fb.Module_ID = 'selected module'
```

Comment: Worked a treat - thanks!! However if u check my Update, my question specific statement isnt returning module specific answers either.. any ideas?

Comment: Try this query - SELECT ans.* FROM tblAnswers ans, tblFeedback fb
WHERE ans.Submission_ID = fb.Submission_ID
AND Module_ID = 'selected module'
AND Q_ID = 'selected question' - BTW, i must note that there is something really weird with your table design, It just feels a bit warped!!

Comment: Also, couldnt help noting your comment about doing agile-style :-) Dont mean to sound preachy but agile style  advocates technical excellence and not using parametrized queries would just not be good programming practice - IMHO!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have correlated table A into Table M or Table F.  This will give you all rows in Table A if there are any modules or feedback anywhere with the provided module ID.  You need to add an AND statement to correlate table A with what's in your EXISTS clause.

```
selectQuery = @"
    SELECT * FROM tblAnswers A 
    WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM tblModules M 
            JOIN tblFeedback F ON M.Module_ID = F.Module_ID 
            WHERE F.Module_ID = @ModuleID
            AND   A.Submission_ID = F.Submission_ID)";
```

Also **please consider** using parameterized queries instead of appending variables into your strings.  This causes SQL Server to use the plan cache more efficiently, which is faster, and also eliminates the possibility of a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I do not know what extra criteria to add with the AND clause. I want all answers (* FROM tblAnswers) for the selected module. Each set of questions is submitted and a submission_ID is recorded for each user in tblFeedback along with a module_ID stating which module they were giving feedback on. How can I retrieve the answers for all questions relating to that module. Apologies, see tables above for a clear definition.

Comment: I know I should be using paramterized queries but its due tomorrow and its functionality over optimisation at this point - agile style

Comment: Please see my edits.  I just now saw your DDL (how could I have missed it?)

Comment: **USING PARAMETERIZED QUERIES IS IN NO WAY "OVER-OPTMIZATION"**  It is in no way "agile".  If you are splicing in parameters into your SQL strings, your job is simply not done yet.  If a programmer submitted this to me with that excuse, he or she would have some answering to do for it.  If a programmer knowingly submitted code with a SQL injection bug to cut corners, that programmer would have to come up with a really good reason for me to want to continue employing them.